# Overloaded router, can't connect to the Internet?

Tags: router

I was transferring about 30gb of files to my home server and streaming some music from soundcloud. I've never tried putting so much bandwidth through my router at once before, and basically everything stopped I couldn't connect to the network on any of my computers.

(I take it I overloaded my router?)

I did a hard factory reset and was able to reset my network and everything, got all of my settings back to normal, even did a firmware upgrade...but the router won't pick up the internet connection now. I can see other computers in my network and such, but the internet just doesn't work anymore.

I have tried connecting my modem directly to my computer, which does work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I spent a few hours fixing this, but overlooked the "Clone Mac Address" section. I cloned my main computer's Mac Address and got everything back up and working again. Don't have the rep to post my answer, so here it is.

Comment: Please post this as a proper answer so that you can mark the question as closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I spent a few hours fixing this, but overlooked the "Clone Mac Address" section. I cloned my main computer's Mac Address and got everything back up and working again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your router has died. It's a common problem but also it's a common problem with high traffic that can kill a router. Basically it's very easy to kill a router connection. Linux makes it's easy to adjust the network stack.

Answer (score 0):

Home firewall routers can have a little memory exhaustion issue. Power cycling is the quickest method of getting them back. Not sure if you tried that first, but it's sure a lot less inconvenient than wiping and starting from scratch.

I have this Netgear box here that will be drop kicked out the door when I get tired of the weekly power plug yank and can be bothered to replace it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. It would power on but I couldn't even get into the gateway. :(

Comment: Yipes, it probably had something wrong with the firmware then. A hard power off should have allowed it to read the NVRAM and come back online. Your firmware upgrade should prevent this happening again.